# WMI Query - 2008 Performace counters alerts

Tags: vbscript, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2, performancecounter, wmi-query

I have a set of performance counters alerts on windows 2008 server, which I configured to write in the Event Viewer once the alert is fired.

It does write in this event viewer "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Diagnosis-PLA/Operational"

I am trying to write a WMI query, in vbscript file, against this event viewer to read the events there.

Here is my query:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_NtLogEvent where Logfile = 'Microsoft-Windows-Bits-Client%4Operational'")
```

The problem is: when I check colItems.count, it returns zero, however I know that there are events there, I can see them when I navigate to the event viewer.

The same query works fine if I query the 'Application' event viewer:

```
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_NtLogEvent where Logfile = 'Application'")
```

It returns the count correctly.

Any idea what the problem is in the first query?

Comment: All the logs are saved in here C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs, I can see the Application.evtx log file, as well as the Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-PLA%4Operational.evtx log file. I am still confused over why querying the Application log returns results while the other one doesn't. I am not sure if it is because of the "%4" encoding character in the file name or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMI doesn't support Event Tracing for Windows event logs. The Application event log (for which your query is working) is a classic event log that does not use the Windows Eventing technology. The Win32_NtLogEvent exposes events logged in classic event logs, however it does **not** expose events from the more recent event logs (introduced in Vista). You can however read these logs using the PowerShell cmdlet **Get-WinEvent**.

Comment: I am not looking for a tracing mechanism against the events. I just want to write a simple query against this log. It works fine against the Application event log.